# how to make Excel/Access data have more than one quantity in a table?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Sorry for the confusing question, I'm not sure how to word it right: here's a mock sample of my data

```
Name: Cheeseburger
Date: 1/20/2011
Stock: 30
Price: 200
Name: Hamburger
Date: 1/20/2011
Stock: 12
Price: 180
Name: Cheeseburger
Date: 1/21/2011
Stock: 31
Price: 210
...
```

I will have to make a table in excel or access capable of looking up the stock and price trends of a particular brand through time.

Trouble is, I have two independent variables (Stock, Price) and two known dependent variables (Name, Date).

So, I **cannot** use a simple table where the x axis is the name, y axis is the time, and the cells represent a quantity - each cell have to represent **two** quantities (Stock, Price)

Does anyone know how to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: Homework maybe?

Comment: not quite - just a project I'm working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't confuse data structure with data analysis.

Your data have four variables: name, date, stock, price, which together represent a single unit-block and so the natural way to organize them is:

```
Name              date  Stock Price
-----------------------------------
Cheeseburger  1/20/2011    30   200
Hamburger     1/20/2011    12   180
Cheeseburger  1/21/2011     3   210
```

Obviously when you have to summarize your data in a 2x2 table, you have to choose which variable titles the rows, which one titles the columns and which one gives values. But remember: first comes data structure, then come summary tables.

Are you interested in brand price trend? Build a table Name x Date with cells containing price values.

Are you interested in brand stock trend? Build a table Name x Date with cells containing stock values.